# System of linear equations with coefficient belonging in finite field has $25$ solutions. $3$ Questions with my answers, are they true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let' say that a system of linear equations with coefficient belonging in finite field has 25 solutions. It means that:

- characteristics of finite field is equal to $5$ - I think that's true. The number of solutions can be devided by 5, and that is a prime number
- the system of linear equations is homogeneous - that's false, I don't see why that would be true
- field of the coefficient is $\mathbb{Z_5}$ - that's true, same as the first one

Could anybody correct my mistakes if there are any?

Comment: If you mean coefficients, then for part 3 you should consider the possibility that the field $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic 5 but $|\mathbb{F}| > 5$.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry, I'm not from english-speaking country

Comment: What other fields besides $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ do you know of with characteristic 5?

Comment: I know only that one. I am just starting with linear algebra.

Comment: This problem is probably coming from  a book that assumes some knowledge about finite fields, so you should be aware of that (and either acquire the appropriate prerequisites, or find a book for which you already have knowledge of the prerequisites). But there is a finite field of order 25, which has characteristic 5; it is also a possibility for the coefficient field of your system of equations.